# How to extend an image size for CNN training that the CNN won't notice it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I am making object detection for detecting cars. I am using [this dataset](https://ai.stanford.edu/%7Ejkrause/cars/car_dataset.html). The problem with this dataset is that on the most of the images the car is exactly at the center of the image and there's not a much space left to add any randomness. I need to somehow extend those images that the CNN wont see the old image borders and find the car using them. I ended up using mirrored and blurred original image with some noise to extend the image. Blur and noise are essential for the CNN not to detect the mirrored cars. Here is my function (images are in the format used by OpenCV, 1 float-point color channel):

```
import numpy as np
import random

def extend_image(image: np.ndarray, blur_steps: int=10, noize_steps: int=10) -> np.ndarray:
    image2 = np.ndarray(shape=(image.shape[0] * 3, image.shape[1] * 3) + image.shape[2:], dtype=image.dtype)
    
    image2[image.shape[0]: image.shape[0] * 2, image.shape[1]: image.shape[1] * 2] = image
    
    image2[image.shape[0] * 2: image.shape[0] * 3, image.shape[1]: image.shape[1] * 2] =\
    image2[0: image.shape[0], image.shape[1]: image.shape[1] * 2] = image[::-1, :]
    
    image2[image.shape[0]: image.shape[0] * 2, image.shape[1] * 2: image.shape[1] * 3] =\
    image2[image.shape[0]: image.shape[0] * 2, 0: image.shape[1]] = image[:, ::-1]
    
    image2[image.shape[0] * 2: image.shape[0] * 3, image.shape[1] * 2: image.shape[1] * 3] =\
    image2[0: image.shape[0], image.shape[1] * 2: image.shape[1] * 3] =\
    image2[image.shape[0] * 2: image.shape[0] * 3, 0: image.shape[1]] =\
    image2[0: image.shape[0], 0: image.shape[1]] = image[::-1, ::-1]

    k = np.ones(image2.shape[:2], dtype=float)
    k[: image.shape[0], :] *= np.arange(0., 1., 1. / (image.shape[0] - .5)).reshape(image.shape[0], 1)
    k[image.shape[0] * 2:, :] *= np.arange(1., 0., -1. / (image.shape[0] - .5)).reshape(image.shape[0], 1)
    k[:, : image.shape[1]] *= np.arange(0., 1., 1. / (image.shape[1] - .5)).reshape(1, image.shape[1])
    k[:, image.shape[1] * 2:] *= np.arange(1., 0., -1. / (image.shape[1] - .5)).reshape(1, image.shape[1])

    k1 = k[1: -1, 1: -1]
    k2 = (1. - k[1: -1, 1: -1]) * .25
    image2_old = np.empty_like(image2)
    for _ in range(blur_steps):
        image2_old[...] = image2
        image2[1: -1, 1: -1] = image2_old[1: -1, 1: -1] * k1 + (image2_old[2:, 1: -1] + image2_old[: -2, 1: -1] + image2_old[1: -1, 2:] + image2_old[1: -1, : -2]) * k2
        image2[0, :] = image2_old[1, :]
        image2[-1, :] = image2_old[-2, :]
        image2[:, 0] = image2_old[:, 1]
        image2[:, -1] = image2_old[:, -2]
    
    for _ in range(noize_steps):
        f = np.random.rand(*k1.shape) >= k1
        xs, ys = random.choice([(0, -1), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 0), (-1, -1)])
        image2[1 + ys: image2.shape[0] - 1 + ys, 1 + xs: image2.shape[1] - 1 + xs][f], image2[1: -1, 1: -1][f] = image2[1: -1, 1: -1][f], image2[1 + ys: image2.shape[0] - 1 + ys, 1 + xs: image2.shape[1] - 1 + xs][f]

    image2 *= k ** .6

    return image2
```

Here is what I've got:

[image: The result]

But it seems that my CNN is still able to see the old image borders and use them.

Maybe you know an already existing method or even an implemented function for doing this properly? Or any links to a paper on this problem?

Comment: maybe adding random padding on the borders? but I would say that the best solution is to change dataset

Comment: @Alberto Sinigaglia , what do you mean by "random padding"? Just fill all extra area with random numbers? That should be worse than my solution.  It should be easy for the CNN to see where the padding area begins. About dataset. May be you know a better dataset? That should be great. I am also already using COCO dataset, but there's not a lot car images and many of those images are trash (especially when car is closed by other objects and you can barely see it). After filtering I ended up with like 1500-2000 images.